# No such file or director in $PATH

Tags: 12.04, environment-variables

I wanted to be able to run program from anywhere without adding `./`, so I edited `~/.bashrc` to contain this line

```
export PATH=$PATH:.
```

Now when I type `echo $PATH` I get

```
[......]:/home/yotam/omnetpp-4.2.2/bin:.: No such file or directory
```

Why is that?
Also, I'm not sure about why using `export`, I get the same result if I just type `PATH=$PATH:more_valuew` without export. So what's the difference?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the command contained to the directory described to the environment variable **PATH** can perform without `./` .

In this case, if you want to add current directory in **PATH**,

Replace to this:

```
export PATH=$PATH:./:
```

**In General** :

To make a temporary change the value of an environment variable enter the command:

```
VARNAME=value_of_variable
```

This value will remain until you exit from the shell you are working in.

To make other programs that use the variable aware of the new value enter the command:

```
export VARNAME
```

Comment: Oh well the omnetpp is no really related to the issue, my bed. I just want to be able to run programs from anywhere so I want ./ to be in my PATH

Comment: OK, I rewrote the above description.